# Jacoco agent - no output

Tags: java, spring, docker, gradle, jacoco

So here is the gist...

I use `docker-compose`. My app is just a collection of REST services (spring boot w/ embedded tomcat) so basically I stick to testing endpoints. Whenever I wish to build project with tests (which are in a whole separate module) I use gradle and gradle docker-compose plugin. What happens is that during full build after compilation, docker-compose gradle plugin fires up all services, waits until app container is up and healthy and just executes a bunch of http requests (tests).

So my idea is - during full CI build, launch app in docker container with jacoco agent, that would generate coverage data when all the http tests are executed. But the file output always stays empty.

I add following to `JAVA_OPTS` to app container
`-javaagent:\jacoco\jacocoagent.jar=destfile=\tmp\jacoco.exec,includes=my.company.*,append=true,dumponexit=false`

And the `\tmp\jacoco.exec` is created but its stays at 0 bytes.
Jacoco version I use is `0.7.9`. Am I doing something wrong or don't I understand what jacoco agent is all about?

Answer (score 1):

`dumponexit=false` together with `destfile=...` means that file will not be written on VM shutdown (http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html), but only on API request (http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api/org/jacoco/agent/rt/IAgent.html#dump(boolean)), which is not your intention, I guess. So set `dumponexit` to `true`, or don't specify it at all since `true` is a default.

Comment: Ah yes, I went through jacoco sources on github. I figured that best option would be to pull the exec data while running agent with `tcpserver` mode.

Comment: @Godin is it possible to have the coverage data written to `jacoco.exec` on the fly? For example: If I start up a spring boot application and call its endpoints, I need the coverage reports to be written as each endpoint is called. Basically I want to eliminate the need for the target jar to be terminated to obtain the coverage report